# Does Office Web Apps Require An Enterprise License?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, office-web-apps

We have the OWA services running in our SharePoint 2010 Farm.  Does OWA require enterprise license?

Comment: you are checking for 2010 or 2013?

Comment: For 2010 but I would also like to know for 2013.

Answer (score 5):

Office Web Apps Licensing has recently changed (11-24-2014) in regard to SharePoint 2013, when SP2103 was first released, there was no license needed for "Read only" access, and Office client license needed for "edit" (on your honor enforcement).

This has been changed (and the download location changed). You now need an Enterprise Agreement to install it all (read only or Edit). The download is now located with your Office 2013 client download on your Volume license Service center.  (This was confirmed by Pre-sales on Jan 15) ... (http://blogs.technet.com/b/office_sustained_engineering/archive/2014/10/22/web-apps-server-removal-from-download-center.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Office Web Apps have no dependency on your SharePoint licensing model; instead they are licensed with Office 2010 Professional Plus and Office 2010 Standard licenses. If you have volume license for either Office Professional Plus or Office Standard, then you are already licensed for Office Web App.

More details

http://blogs.devhorizon.com/reza/2012/05/09/office-web-app-licensing/

Comment: does this imply that end-users are only licensed on devices that already have the Office client installed.  But in the use case common for Office Web Apps a lot of users would be using it from mobile devices (e.g. iPad) which would not have Office client installed.